# Copy one item from an ArrayList to another ArrayList Java 8

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm currently working on an uni project where I have a simple shop where I can create products, store them into an `ArrayList`, and then, I want to select some of those products and store them into another `ArrayList`.
The idea is select a product (giving the index) from `productList` and store it on `shoppingCartList`.

What I currently have:

```
ArrayList<Producto> listaProductos = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Pedido> listaPedido = new ArrayList<>();
```

I have already done the code for creating, removing, modifying and listing the products from `listaProductos` which is where I store all the products, so the only thing I need is a method to select a specific item given an index, and store to `listaPedido`, but I can't find a proper way to do that, I only know how to copy ALL the `ArrayList` to another.

So my question is, how to copy one item from an `ArrayList` to another?

Comment: `ArrayList` has a [`get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) method and an [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) method. You don't need much else.

Comment: I'm pretty new using Java (only 2 months) and I can't figure how to do that @FedericoklezCulloca if you could give an example

Comment: I'm afraid that's all the help I can give since you didn't explain how a `Producto` can be converted to a `Pedido` (or how they are related anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get()` method to get a item at index from `ArrayList`

```
Producto product = listaProductos.get(index);
```

Where index is a integer

Use `add()` method to add it to second list , Since the second list is of type `Pedido` you can't add it unless it is of compatible type. You need to convert your `Producto` object to `Pedido` to do that you can create a new `Pedido' object and set all the attributes from the 'Producto' , if you have getters and setters you can do like this

```
Pedido pedido = new Pedido();
pedido.set...(product.get...()); //for all other fields 
listaPedido.add(pedido);
```

If getters and setters is not written and attributes are `public` you can directly assign like

```
pedido.attributeName = producto.attribute;
```

Take a look into documentation:[ArrayList JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)